# Ensure Unique Key from Multiple Tables

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables that are used in a view.

If the data does not exist in List tbl then use TaxRiskList instead.

However, TaxRiskListID has a value of 1, which is also a value in VendorID in List tbl.

How can I ensure correct value is returned?

```
SELECT r.RecipientID, r.[Email], r.[Name], COALESCE(l.VendorName,trl.TaxRiskListName) as VendorName
FROM [Fund.Accounting.Model.Vendors].[Recipients] r
LEFT JOIN
        [Fund.Accounting.Model.Vendors].List l
        ON l.VendorID = r.VendorID
    LEFT JOIN
        [Fund.Accounting.Model.Vendors].TaxRiskList trl
        ON trl.TaxRiskListID = r.VendorID
```

As an example, in table C the VendorID should actually relate to table A.

However, because table B has the same VendorID value i.e. 5, then table B value is always returned in the select query.

The VendorID column is a FK for table A and table B. So in reality the value 5 could be in table C for both tbl A and tbl B. I guess I need another column to flag what the related tbl is?

[image]

Comment: What problem do you have with this query? Seems correct.

Comment: The problem I have is that VendorID in List table has a value=1. Also TaxRiskListID in TaxRiskList table also has a value=1. If both are mapped to VendorID in Recipients table, then the List table value will always be used.

Comment: So do I need another column to specify what related tbl to use?

Comment: You say *"If the data does not exist in List tbl then use TaxRiskList instead."* So, if the `List.VendorID` is 1, data exists in the List table and TaxRiskList should not (and isn't) used. I don't see the problem. Perhaps you can edit the question and clarify with sample data from the 3 tables and expected result.

Comment: Why is `Recipients.VendorID` allowed to be treated as a reference to `TaxRiskList.TaxRiskListID`? More generally, why are you using a single column to reference two different columns (in two different tables, too)?